# Google scripts to copy and repeat row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi all I'm no good with scripts at all, just need some help, what I want to do is copy and repeat cells a,b,c,d,e, based on info in cells F and G.

In cells d and e are dates and they need to increase by value in cell F and keep repeating based on value in G, I have made a sample sheet, on the sheet input is the data, and on sheet output it shows the results I would need. But all info needs to stay on the input sheet not a different sheet. Hope u can understand what I mean when u see the sample sheet. On the sheet in cell f it says weeks, this would be better in days then weeks.

```
Title   Description     Location        Start Time      End Time     repeate every  how many times to repeat                                                                            
test    tester          here            9/7/17 20:00    9/7/17 20:10    2 weeks     4                                                                           
fake    data            home            15/7/17 15:00   15/7/17 16:00   4 weeks     3
```

[original Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wzv51Yo5O6YhY01H3VPEoaFrsV4eryeVrvtHE1rDPPY)

The overall goal I am trying to get is to be able to add reoccurring events to Google calendar with scripts automatically when submitted with a form, but if I can repeat the data I need in the sheets I can then sync it to the calendar automatically and then I can set the reoccurring events based on days as I believe the reoccurring event for calendar only lets u do daily weekly monthly..

Or Can anyone point me to a site where I may find some info to help me please?

Comment: Can anyone point me to a site where I may find some info to help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the repeat to days instead of weeks.

```
function repeatingEvents() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Repeat');
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();//Get all of the data on the sheet
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var day=86400000;//milliseconds in a day
    var week=604800000;//millisecond in a week
    for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      if(rngA[i][6]>0)//If the number of repeats is greater than zero
      {
        var cnt=Number(rngA[i][6]);//cnt is number of repeats
        for(var n=0;n<cnt;n++)
        {
          var row=[];
          row.push(rngA[i][0]);//column A
          row.push(rngA[i][1]);//column B
          row.push(rngA[i][2]);//column C
          row.push(new Date(rngA[i][3].getTime() + (rngA[i][5] * (n + 1) * day)));//old date time plus repeat duration * repeat count * milliseconds in a day in column D
          row.push(new Date(rngA[i][4].getTime() + (rngA[i][5] * (n + 1) * day)));//column E
          row.push(rngA[i][5]);//Column F
          row.push('');//column G get zeroed out so script won't come back and do it again without human interaction
          sht.appendRow(row);//add new event
         }
         sht.getRange(i+1,7).setValue(0);//zero out initial number of repeats because I use this to determine when repeats are required
      }
    }
    sht.getRange(2,1,sht.getLastRow(),sht.getLastColumn()).sort({column:4,ascending:true});//Sort Spreadsheet by starting date
}
```

Here's what my spreadsheet looks like.

[image]

Okay I changed the code to accomodate your recent change of adding the id.  It's already in your spreadsheet and I repeat it here.  For reference purposes.

```
function repeatingEvents() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('input');
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();//Get all of the data on the sheet
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var day=86400000;//milliseconds in a day
    var week=604800000;//millisecond in a week
    for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      if(rngA[i][7]>0)//If the number of repeats is greater than zero
      {
        var cnt=Number(rngA[i][7]);//cnt is number of repeats
        for(var n=0;n<cnt;n++)
        {
          var row=[];
          row.push(rngA[i][0]);//A
          row.push(rngA[i][1]);//B
          row.push(rngA[i][2]);//C
          row.push(new Date(rngA[i][3].getTime() + (rngA[i][6] * (n + 1) * day)));//old date time plus repeat duration * repeat count * milliseconds in a day D
          row.push(new Date(rngA[i][4].getTime() + (rngA[i][6] * (n + 1) * day)));//E
          row.push(rngA[i][5]);//F
          row.push(rngA[i][6]);//G
          row.push('');//H
          sht.appendRow(row);//add new event
         }
         sht.getRange(i+1,8).setValue(0);//zero out initial number of repeats because I use this to determine when repeats are required
      }
    }
    sht.getRange(2,1,sht.getLastRow(),sht.getLastColumn()).sort({column:4,ascending:true});//Sort Spreadsheet by starting date
}
```

Comment: That works well thank you very much, If you have time to explain each part of it please do, if not its not a problem, I just want to learn as well..

Comment: Checkout the comments.  I commented on the highlights.  It's not very complicated.

Comment: Thanks that helps, is there a way to call another function once this function has ended, or would I just have to set them on triggers?

Comment: You could put the new function call at the end of this script.  But remember both scripts have to finish in 6 minutes or less.

Comment: Ok cool thanks, the next script is to send it all to a Google Calender, next bit I'm going to try and do is check the end dates and if end date has gone then to move that row to another sheet, but should be easier to work out how to do that, thanks again.

Comment: okay I think I've got changed to accommodate the additional column

Answer (score 0):

I have changed column F and G to G and H, i tried to edit the script to work with this, all seems to work apart from when it adds the days to repeat it still adds them in F and not G cant seem to work out why?

```js
function repeatingEvents() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Calendar');
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();//Get all of the data on the sheet
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var day=86400000;//milliseconds in a day
    var week=604800000;//millisecond in a week
    for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      if(rngA[i][7]>0)//If the number of repeats is greater than zero
      {
        var cnt=Number(rngA[i][7]);//cnt is number of repeats
        for(var n=0;n<cnt;n++)
        {
          var row=[];
          row.push(rngA[i][0]);//A
          row.push(rngA[i][1]);//B
          row.push(rngA[i][2]);//C
          row.push(new Date(rngA[i][3].getTime() + (rngA[i][6] * (n + 1) * day)));//old date time plus repeat duration * repeat count * milliseconds in a day D
          row.push(new Date(rngA[i][4].getTime() + (rngA[i][6] * (n + 1) * day)));//E
          row.push(rngA[i][5]);//E This needs to be here other wise 6 and 7 become 5 & 6
          row.push(rngA[i][6]);//F
          row.push(rngA[i][7]);//G
          sht.appendRow(row);//add new event
         }
         sht.getRange(i+1,8).setValue(0);//zero out initial number of repeats because I use this to determine when repeats are required
      }
    }
    sht.getRange(2,1,sht.getLastRow(),sht.getLastColumn()).sort({column:4,ascending:true});//Sort Spreadsheet by starting date
}
```

Comment: I saw your comments and I guess that you added a column between E and F.  So I modified the row that gets appended  to the repeated rows.  Look at my edits to the script.  I also added column letters.   I'm just copying whatever was in the new column F back into that column on the appended rows.  If you added a new column to another position then change it on your spreadsheet so I can make the appropriate corrections for you.

Comment: Where you put added column that is where I added one that's for id when adding to google calendar, but that's a massive script to change and I don't understand a lot of it, I'm just trying to get the Calender script to run once this one finishes, but it might be easier to set the script to run ever hour instead, unless you got any suggestions, thanks again for your help I do really appreciate the help.

Comment: if you have a look at the original Google sheet i posted u will see the output i get when i run the script, and even when i change the script to try align up i must be missing something as it still put the repeat days in column F.

Comment: Thanks that part is all working now, i have added in the sync to calendar script i found to the linked sheet here, it did work fine to start with but has stopped working now, im getting a error on line 337, i worked out the error is because of the extra 3 columns i added (G,H and I) but not sure how to fix it, if you have time could u please look at it, line 41 is for cal id but i removed the ID, columns G,H and I would not need to be synced to calendar, thanks again.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that  script perhaps you should contact the author regarding that error or submit it as another question.  There may be others on this site that know about that script.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help, is there a way to mark this as done?

Comment: I you would check off my answer I would appreciate that.  Thanks